# WinSCP login issue with sudo

Tags: sftp, openssh, tty, winscp

I am trying to login using WinSCP using correct username and password.

Under *Environment > SFTP > SFTP Server* I have specified `sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

Under *Session* I type in the *Host name*, *User name* and *Password*.

When I click on Login I get

> Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command  exit status 1.
>
> Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running a SFTP server?
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

This is link to a complete log http://pastebin.com/GcmpK2kj

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you enable password-less `sudo` to the `sftp-server`. And make sure that the `sudoers` option `requiretty` is turned off.

Detailed instructions are in WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)